# Does anyone know of a public domain recording of Tanakh chapters or verses?

Tags: hebrew, tanach, torah-reading

The question title explains it all -- I'm looking for a public domain audio recording of the Tanakh.  For example, these people have recorded Genesis:
http://librivox.org/the-bible-the-book-of-genesis/

Thanks

Comment: not public domain, but this site has a recording each verse in the torah and haftorah: http://bible.ort.org/intro1.asp

Comment: I assume you refer want it in Hebrew?

Comment: Are you looking for something free or something you can re-use without having to worry about licensing?

Comment: @YaakovKuperman the latter, something I can re-use without having to worry about licensing

Comment: @Menachem unfortunately, it's gotta be public domain or thereabouts.  if the link you provided actually provides separate files for each verse, that'd be great (in that respect).  thank you

Comment: Dear OP:  May I ask:  Why would you like an audio recording of Tanach?  And why public-domain?

Comment: Hey @unforgettableid, I'm working on a project that I want to be available to the public, and I don't want to have to worry about licensing.

Comment: @WalrustheCat:  Got it.  More questions:  1.  Is your project a computer software package?  A smartphone app?  Something else?  2.  What license do you think you'd like to release it under?  (Public domain is an extraordinarily uncommon license choice, and there may be some legal problems in some jurisdictions with choosing it.)  3.  Are you willing to release a package where the code is under one license and the data is under another?  4.  Do you want to charge money for people to purchase or use your project?  5.  Do you want donations?  6.  Could you please tell us more about your project?

Comment: Web service (possible mobile client later.)  No donations.  No charges.  I don't care about protecting my intellectual property as far as the code goes, and I just want to be unencumbered as to the use of the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are recordings of the Torah, haftaros, Five Megillos, and parts of other books of Tanach on Hebrew Wikisource, under the section ["Vayavinu Bamikra"](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%95%D7%99%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95_%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90) (not to be confused with the CD of that name mentioned in [DoubleAA's comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16297/does-anyone-know-of-a-public-domain-recording-of-tanakh-chapters-or-verses#comment34264_16305)).

They're not quite public domain, but pretty close - under the Creative Commons "Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported" license, the same as what's used for StackExchange sites, including this one.

Comment: Welcs. I'll _bl"n_ delete your comment, and mine, when I assume you've read this.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, so in this scenario, I can use these recordings and just post an attribution? I'm going to accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

**The recordings referenced herein are not public domain.**

Much of Tana"ch is available for streaming, read with cantillation by Rav Jeremy Weider on yutorah.org. Typing "laining" in the search field at the top takes you right to them. (They are also in the "Series" tab under "Laining" if you are on the browsing page.)

[Here](http://www.yutorah.org/terms_of_use.htm) are yutorah's Terms of Use.

Comment: Those recordings are even less in the public domain than the others on the site as they are not available for download. In fact I know that Rabbi Weider sells/sold a CD with those recordings on it called Vayavinu Bamiqra. So these are definitely not public.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I'm definitely looking for something I can use and not get in trouble for :-)

Comment: Thanks @DoubleAA. Not trying to incriminate anyone here. I will place a bold disclaimer.

Comment: That said, the CD is an excellent resource with recordings of all the parshot, haftorot and megillot, as well as a number of shiurim on dikduk as it relates to proper keriat hatorah.

Answer (score 2):

Go to archive.org and search Dan Be'eri. You'll find both cantillation and narration formats. Mostly complete and downloadable.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Peter! Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Although they may or may not be in the public domain, I found these on Mechon-Mamre's website:

- http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt00.htm
- http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/ptmp3prq.htm

You can download these MP3 files either chapter-by-chapter, or an entire book at a time.

Comment: These are not pubic domain either.

Comment: Thanks @Adam Mosheh, but it's not too hard to find audio files.  The trick is finding the appropriate license.

Answer (score 1):

[Chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/multimedia/media_cdo/aid/982057/jewish/Torah-Reading-Recordings.htm) allows you to download the recordings of the Torah readings, and so I assume that means that they are in the public domain. Of course, these are not the Tanach and not even the entire Torah portions, just the amount read in synagogue.